# python function or operation that returns float("nan")

Tags: python, python-3.x, floating-point

the [IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic (IEEE 754)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) requires the existence of a `float` (or two...) that is called `nan` (not a number).

there are two ways to get `nan` (that i know of)

```
nan = float("nan")
#  or
from math import nan
```

but is there a **mathematical** function i can perform on `floats` **in the standard library** that returns `nan`?

the obvious ideas like `math.sqrt(-1)` (and similar) do not return `nan` but raise `ValueError: math domain error`.

or are `nan`s only meant for data where values are missing and are never supposed to be returned by a function?

(is there also something that returns `math.inf`? again, the obvious `1/0` raises a `ZeroDivisionError`).

Comment: "but is there a function or an operation i can perform on floats in the standard library that returns nan?" I don't understand how there is a question. You already showed two ways that do not require a third-party library. "or are nans only meant for data where values are missing and are never supposed to be returned by a function?" If the question is supposed to be "why is there such a thing as `nan` defined in the standard?", I am pretty sure that is already explained **by the standard**.

Comment: not what i mean. should probably rephrase... is there e.g. a mathematical operation that returns `nan`? or a mathematical function in the stdlib? that may be more precise. my examples are not function calls (well `float` is but that is a special case...)

Comment: FWIW, you can also directly "reinterpret" raw data using the `struct` module. For example, using the half-float format for compactness, `struct.unpack('e', b'\x00~')` gives inf, and `struct.unpack('e', b'\x00|')` gives nan. However, I don't think that meets your requirements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`math.inf - math.inf` gives `nan`.

(`1e308 + 1e308` or just `1e309` give `inf`.)

Answer (score 3):

Generating **`NaN`**:

- `math.inf * 0` results to `nan`

> (+∞) × 0 = NaN

- `+` (on opposite signs) and `/` (on any sign) operations between `math.inf`s
- and bonus case: generating 2 `nan`s:

  ```
  In [576]: divmod(math.inf, 1)
  Out[576]: (nan, nan)
  ```